# How to change error and failure detection in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, hook, pytest

In pytest, I want to report all uncaught `AssertionError` exceptions as `Failure` and all other uncaught exceptions as `Errors` (instead of the default behavior of reporting all uncaught exceptions in setup method as `Errors` while all uncaught exceptions in test cases and UUT as `Failure`).  I thought it could be done with pytest hooks.  However, "passed", "skipped", and "failed" seem to be the only valid outcome values in `TestReport` object.

So,

1. Is it possible to add "error" as a valid outcome and let the rest of pytest do the appropriate reporting, i.e., display *E/ERROR* instead of *F/FAILURE* on console output?
2. If so, what would be the ideal part of the source to do this?
3. If we cannot add "error" as a valid outcome, then what would be the best way to inject this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Self answer]

[pytest-finer-verdicts plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-finer-verdicts/) achieves this behavior :)